# .NET 3.5 feature unavailable in Windows Server 2008 - only option is 3.0

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-server-2008, .net-3.0

I have an application I need to install in Windows Server 2008.  It requires .NET 3.5 or higher and after running Windows Update I've got version 4.0 installed.  However, in 'Add Features' the only option I have is to add .NET Framework 3.0.  Anyone have an idea of what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little diverted from answering your question directly, but may answer it indirectly...

At work our server only allows selection of .NET `1.1` and `2.0.50727.4927` (from within IIS' ASP.NET tab). However, we do run `3.5` websites (`3.0` was never installed individually, I think).

But how? Well, I believe it to be because those are the first two versions which, between them, have a substantial difference in the core of the framework - which means you have to select the version of the `CLR` to differentiate appropriately (which is what these server values represent); though with `3.5` it is actually only a number of peripheral libraries which make up the framework that have changed, and they can all be loaded using the `2.0` `CLR`, therefore they are.

*Long story short:* despite what it looks like it is telling you, selection of the `2.0` `CLR` in IIS allows you to run applications anywhere up to `3.5` within your environment.

Just make sure you know which `CLR` version the application has been developed for and select the correct one.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_3.5#.NET_Framework_3.5):

> Version 3.5 of the .NET Framework was
>   released on 19 November 2007, but it
>   is not included with Windows Server
>   2008. As with .NET Framework 3.0, version 3.5 uses the CLR of version
>   2.0. In addition, it installs .NET Framework 2.0 SP1, (installs .NET
>   Framework 2.0 SP2 with 3.5 SP1) and
>   .NET Framework 3.0 SP1 (installs .NET
>   Framework 3.0 SP2 with 3.5 SP1), which
>   adds some methods and properties to
>   the BCL classes in version 2.0 which
>   are required for version 3.5 features
>   such as Language Integrated Query
>   (LINQ). These changes do not affect
>   applications written for version 2.0,
>   however.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have .NET 4.0 (the full version, not just the Client Profile)installed, you automatically have every older version as well.